# Change a Combobox's selectedIndex from ViewModel and when the Combobox is binded

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox, selectedindex

I want to have the selected index of a combobox change based on code from the ViewModel. Is this possible?

This is how my combobox is set up:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbModels" DisplayMemberPath="ModelItemTextbox"
          SelectedItem="ItemNameTextbox" SelectionChanged="ModelSelectionChange" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding ModelComboList}">
</ComboBox>
```

Something else, my bindings don't work unless I have the SelectedItem set to "ItemNameTextbox". The Combobox is binded to an observableCollection.

```
private ObservableCollection<ModelComboListModel> _modelcombolist = new ObservableCollection<ModelComboListModel>();
    public ObservableCollection<ModelComboListModel> ModelComboList
    {
        get { return _modelcombolist; }
        set
        {
            _modelcombolist = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ModelComboList");
        }
    }
```

And the class:

```
public class ModelComboListModel
{

    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public string ItemId { get; set; }

    //public override string ToString()
    //{
    //    return $"ID:{ModelItemId} | {ModelItemName}";
    //}

    public string ItemTextbox
    {
        get
        {
            return $"{ ItemId }: {ItemName}";
        }
    }

}
```

The list just contains items and their id's.

Is there a good trick for changing the selectedindex from the ViewModel? I can't find anything useful on google or here :(

Comment: @Clemens with all due respect to you or whoever marked this as a duplicate, said duplicate is not a duplicate, in my opinion. This question is about how to change the selected index in a combobox from within the view model and reflect the change in the view. The 'duplicate' question asks about finding the selected item in the view model after the SelectionChanged trigger is invoked. The answers are also different as they do not address use of `SelectedIndex`. That being said, I would be shocked if a true duplicate to this question does not, in fact, already exist.

Comment: Wether you update the view from the view model or the view model from the view is irrelevant. The point is that you use data binding for one of the mentioned properties. They all bind TwoWay by default.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to bind to the `SelectedIndex` property in your `ComboBox`. Then you can be strategic with your `get`s and `set`s in the view model to get the behavior you are looking for. In this example I made a `TextBox` that can be used to change the index of the `ComboBox`:

```
<StackPanel>
    <ComboBox x:Name="cmbModels" 
      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=OneWay}"
      SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedItemIndex}"
      ItemsSource="{Binding ModelComboList}"
              Margin="5">
    </ComboBox>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding ItemSelect}"
               Margin="5"/>
</StackPanel>
```

View Model:

```
internal class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string? propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler? handler = PropertyChanged;
            handler?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private int _selectedItemIndex = 0;
    public int SelectedItemIndex
    {
        get => _selectedItemIndex;
        set
        {
            _selectedItemIndex = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<string> ModelComboList { get; } = new() { "Item", "Foo", "Bar" };// populate with more items as needed

    public string SelectedItem => ModelComboList[_selectedItemIndex];

    public string ItemSelect
    {
        get => _selectedItemIndex.ToString();
        set
        {
            if (int.Parse(value) < 0 || int.Parse(value) > ModelComboList.Count)
                SelectedItemIndex = 0;
            else
                SelectedItemIndex = int.Parse(value);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I had assumed the SelectedIndex binding wasn't working for me after a previous try. But reviewing your answer had me notice I had a simple mis-type in my index counter.